# In Rey's vision, whose voice says "These are your first steps"?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In The Force Awakens, she has a vision, and a voice says:

> These are your first steps

Now a number of former Jedi have become 'luminous beings' (not this crude matter). I'm trying to work out which one it is. It seems to be one of Yoda, Obi-Wan, Qui-Gon or even Anakin.

My question is: **In Rey's vision, whose voice says "These are your first steps"?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From Entertainment Weekly interview with J.J. Abrams ["Obi-Wan and Yoda are secretly in Star Wars: The Force Awakens – exclusive"](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/20/jj-abrams-reveals-obi-wan-and-yoda-are-star-wars-force-awakens):

> “You do hear a little bit of Yoda. You hear Luke yelling out, ‘Nooo!’ from that moment in Empire. **And you hear Obi-Wan at the end say, ‘Rey … these are your first steps,’” Abrams says. “Here’s the cool part. We asked Ewan McGregor to come in and do the line**. And he was awesome and we were very grateful. He was incredibly sweet and handsome, and all that stuff. Then he rode off on his motorcycle. Literally the coolest voice over actor ever.”

Comment: I heard somewhere that the "Rey" was gleaned from the old Obi-Wan saying "afraid" somewhere in the original trilogy.

Comment: @Justin - yes. http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2015/12/19/how-to-spot-all-the-star-wars-the-force-awakens-cameos-from-daniel-craig-to-radiohead.html

Comment: Ewan McGregor saying this himself -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHfLx5sqpCU