# Yoda's dialogue in Rey's dream sequence

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

As the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112324/in-reys-vision-whose-voice-says-these-are-your-first-steps) explains, during Rey's "dream"<sup>1</sup> in *The Force Awakens*, we hear Obi-Wan's voice saying:

> Rey...  these are your first steps.

The word "Rey" is a sample edited from Alec Guinness saying "afraid" in one of the OT films;  the rest of the line was a recording of Ewan McGregor made specifically for *The Force Awakens*.  I actually noticed the line when I saw the movie, and I immediately recognized the voice behind the "Rey" portion as that of Alec Guinness.

However, the scene in question is very jarring, fast-paced, disorienting, and confusing, so I had trouble taking in everything that was happening.  In all the commotion and rapid-fire changes of scenery and action, I apparently missed another familiar voice.

According to [this](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/12/20/jj-abrams-reveals-obi-wan-and-yoda-are-star-wars-force-awakens) article, the dream sequence also features a brief vocal performance from Frank Oz as Yoda, but I totally missed it, and now I'm dying to know exactly what Yoda said.

### What does Yoda say during Rey's dream?

Note:  My question is related to [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112324/in-reys-vision-whose-voice-says-these-are-your-first-steps?noredirect=1&lq=1) about what Rey **sees** in her dream, but whereas that question focuses on the visuals, mine is directed at what she **hears *Yoda* say**.

---

<sup>1</sup> *I don't think "dream" is really an accurate description of what is happening, but I don't know what else to call it - "dream", "flashback", "vision", and "hallucination" each convey a bit of what is happening to Rey, but none of these words seem to describe the entirety of the experience in a satisfactory way;  I have opted to use the word "dream" because it is as good as any of the other options, but I think it covers slightly more territory than any of the others do.*

Comment: Force-induced acid trip is my preferred term at this point.

Comment: I'm VTCing this but NOT as a duplicate (because my question explicitly does not address audio yet, for a good reason), but as "opinion based" - basically, as the current answer shows, all we get is guesses from people overhearing a 1 second snippet of meaningless words with no meaningful proof possible till the DVD release, or if we are lucky, final script. (at which point, I WILL add the audio details to my answer making this a duplicate, sorry).

Comment: @DVK - Since it absolutely isn't opinion based, that's a bit bizarre.  The line exists, the movie is out, and we've seen it.  The information is available.  Your argument amounts to "People might be wrong".  That isn't how VTC as opinion based works.

Comment: @WadCheber -  I'm positing that a minor 1-word "line" - among the noise of that dream - is not able to be "information", as everyone will hear different things. Sort of how 50% people get some song lyrics wrong.

Comment: @DVK - the explanation of the Obi Wan bit has been laid out very clearly.  There is no good reason to assume that the same isn't true of the Yoda bit, or that - if the Yoda thing isn't explicitly explained somewhere already - that it won't be explained soon.  The information is there.  The answer is available, whether or not we have it.

Comment: @WadCheber - possible. But if they didn't offer it in the main "who said what in those voices interview", I doubt they would. Either way, as I said, as soon as the sounds have actual proof, I'm adding them to my answer where they belong, so my VTC becomes moot but only because this question will become duplicate.

Comment: @dvk http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/12/20/ewan-mcgregor-has-a-star-wars-the-force-awakens-cameo

Comment: http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/12/24/10-coolest-star-wars-the-force-awakens-easter-eggs-references-and-cameos

Comment: @dvk Confirmed enough for my tastes

Comment: "...related to [this one] about..." FYI, there's no link there.

Comment: @RedCaio - Thanks.  Fixed it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## "Its energy..."

You can hear two words from Yoda, which I believe are *"Its energy"*.

This is a snippet from the sentence ***"Its energy surrounds us and binds us"*** that Yoda uttered while training Luke on Dagobah in *Empire Strikes Back*.

This is what I heard when viewing *The Force Awakens*.  During my second viewing of the film, I made a point of listening closely to sounds and words in the dream sequence.

I also checked the official novelization — neither Obi-Wan's nor Yoda's dialogue appears in the novel.  That being said, I'm reasonably certain that Yoda said *"Its energy".*

This is consistent with the fact that Yoda's dialogue for *The Force Awakens* was excised from existing sound bites, as reported by numerous sources.  For example:

> Oz also recorded some lines for the movie, but the creative team opted to use dialogue featured in past films instead.

([Source](http://www.nydailynews.com/entertainment/movies/obi-wan-yoda-cameo-star-wars-force-awakens-article-1.2472643))

**UPDATE:** The use of the *"Its energy..."* sound bite that I heard has been confirmed [here](http://ca.ign.com/articles/2015/12/20/ewan-mcgregor-has-a-star-wars-the-force-awakens-cameo) — thanks @WadCheber!

**UPDATE:** For completeness, here is the clip of the scene:

Comment: No lines in the script either. Bloody slackers :( May be final screen treatment will have it....

Comment: +1, but what would that mean in a vision to Rey, if that's what he says? Seems to make no sense, unlike OB1 line

Comment: @DVK : Thanks.  It might be as simple as the Force binding her to Luke and Luke's lightsaber, i.e. "its energy surrounds us and *binds us*".

Comment: Found some sources - http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/12/20/ewan-mcgregor-has-a-star-wars-the-force-awakens-cameo  http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/12/20/ewan-mcgregor-has-a-star-wars-the-force-awakens-cameo

Comment: http://boards.theforce.net/threads/confirmed-obi-wans-voice-shouts-rey-in-flashback-sequence.50035921/page-5

Comment: I saw a subtitled theatrical release, and can confirm this answer is correct.

Answer (score -3):

I could have swore he said "your journey is complete" but I didn't hear the dialogue prior, sorry.

Comment: I think the whole was something like "after this your journey is complete"... I'm just not sure..

Comment: Instead of adding a comment below your post, you can [edit] it - much better :-)

Answer (score -4):

I swear I heard yoda say "Rey, it's coming to you" And Obiwan saying "yes Rey.

**DO NOT ASK HOW I HEARD IT I JUST DID.**
But I might have also heard Obiwan saying "Rey, there are more of you"
Then Yoda said "You there are."

Comment: I really did hear it.

Comment: I SWEAR I DID!!!!!

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! If you fell strongly enough about this is there a somehow you can back it up? It seems to contradict the accepted answers that has proven sources.