# Who is the person that says "Rey"?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Who is the person who says "Rey" in the background of the scene from *The Force Awakens* where Rey finds Luke's and Anakin's lightsaber?

Comment: Does [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112324/31394) answer your question? (I haven't closed as duplicate since I'm not 100% sure it's the same scene being asked about.)

Comment: And [here is Ewan McGregor discussing recording this line](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHfLx5sqpCU) (from the comments on the dupe target).